# Extract curve from image

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have troubles with a seemingly easy image processing task. I need to extract a curve from a medical image (the image I attached was fetched from an open source database).

[Raw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXqoi.jpg)

I also have about ~50 images like the attached one, but they have small differences and they vary a bit. I'm afraid it's not something that can be used with ML (due to small dataset)

I tried the following approach a modification of which is working well for blood vessels:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('./img.png')

img_gray = img.copy()
img_gray[img_gray < 70] = 0
img_gray = cv.blur(img_gray * 1.5, (5, 5)).astype(np.uint8)
img_gray = 255 - img_gray
_, img_gray = cv.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap='gray')
plt.savefig('output.png', dpi=600, pad_inches=0, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Then we have the following result:
[Processed curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrvm3.png)

Any ideas of how to improve the filtering, please?

Comment: Please provide the full code, your example does not provide the same output for me given the input image you provide

Comment: @whn I attached the full version of the code, and corrected the photos too, everything should be fine now.

Comment: my output.png, when running  your code straight up does not look like your processed curve image, is that supposed to be the ideal image?

Comment: @whn I rerun the code on another pc and used the same input. The result was the same as in the photo that was attached to this question. Could you send me a photo, which was the result of the work code.